# Canon MP230 won't print on 15.04 Ubuntu

Tags: printing, 15.04

I have a Canon MP230. I can scan with Ubuntu 15.04's simple scanner application, and I can print test pages, but I can't print doc files, pdf files, etc.

What do I need to do to be able to print documents?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Canon PIXMA MP230 after upgrading from 15.04 to 15.10. 
Worked after installing the following Debian driver from Canon Website and adding the printer again in Ubuntu Printers:

http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100465901.html

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf cnijfilter-mp230series-3.80-1-deb.tar.gz
cd cnijfilter-mp230series-3.80-1-deb
sudo ./install.sh
```

Comment: As new to ubuntu comming from Windows 8 and a bit of a dummy how to upgrate 15.04 to 15.10? is there a link to use and upgrate just push the "buttom". I have mess around on I-net and not been able

Comment: 15.12.15 Hi Jens (er du dansk) have just downloaded as came up with the regular updates for 15.04- now going to install canon link and see - Thanks